# Using the name of CC BY-NC 4.0 licensed material

Tags: cc-by-nc

I was wondering, if I am complying fully with the CC BY-NC 4.0 license. Can I keep the name? For example if the name is Abc, my name is Abc Alphabet. Can the author require me to change it and remove any association with his work?

Comment: The name of what? Can you provide more domain specific detail? Briefly, if the author holds a trademark, they probably can.

Comment: OpenSource software(browser extension). I highly doubt he holds a trademark.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You want to adapt a CC BY-NC 4.0 licensed work, and use the same, or a closely related name for your derivative work?

Comment: Yes, that's a correct way to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of a work is covered by copyright, and would be under the same terms of the license. Allowing you to make a derivative work of it,, so ABC Alphabet would be fine.

There *may* be a separate trademark on the name, in which case you should also comply with trademark law.

In general, it's a bad idea to give the impression you are something you are not. I would suggest making it *very* clear you are not ABC, and are not affiliated with ABC, and choosing a name that doesn't give that impression.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Too bad I am short of 4 rep and I cant upvote.

Comment: pngcrush is a pretty good example of this problem.  Apple modified pngcrush so that it creates invalid PNGs as output.  I, the author of the real pngcrush, get blamed for that.  The license requires derivatives to be clearly identified as such, but Apple didn't bother with that.  Search StackOverflow questions about "pngcrush" for details.  I wish they had called their rogue version xpngcrush or something like that.